# Rerouting custom routes when user is not authenticated (Devise, rails gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to reroute a non-authenticated user to my login page, lets say my route is `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in` aka `devise/sessions#new` right now by default devise will edit page when not logged in since this is built in. But any custom routes will just break the app if you're not logged in since it is not apart of the devise reroutes. How do I set these routes to reroutes if not logged in? 
Quoting directly from devise below, i'm still at a loss on how to implement this with my routes, what should the code look like?

goes inside lib

```
  class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
    def redirect_url
       new_user_session_url(:subdomain => 'secure')
    end

    # You need to override respond to eliminate recall
    def respond
      if http_auth?
        http_auth
      else
        redirect
      end
    end
  end
And add the following in config/initializers/devise.rb:

  config.warden do |manager|
    manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
  end
```

goes inside initializers

```
 config.warden do |manager|
    manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this In your **routes.rb**

```
authenticated :user do
  devise_scope :user do
    root to: "dashboard#index"
  end
end

unauthenticated do
  devise_scope :user do
    root to: "homepage#index"
  end
end
```